# Rococo Status & Issues

Tags: parachain, rococo, block-production

lately Rococo has been producing blocks very slowly.
Not sure if this is the best place to ask, but where can we find more information about this? Or where to ask about this if this isn't the correct place?

Not sure if this is completely related but our parachain started getting the following error:

> 2022-06-08 14:39:36 [Relaychain] Skipping chain: unable to gather info about imported block (0xbfeac39ed4511880c6a831bf5eb911ba4756afc93b722b78c41057e44a4afd48, 545029): block is from an ancient session